# How to split cleaned text data into training and testing datasets except for random sampling

Tags: python, text, nlp, text-mining, sampling

I have cleaned and de-duplicated text data with a 'count_raw_id' column which implies the number of raw ids that are mapped to one cleaned id 
A clean id represent that it is unique and has some raw ids mapped to it 
Now i don't want to split my cleaned text data('clean_df') randomly 
I need some Criteria based sampling to create two datasets out of this whole cleaned file of about 2k rows one to train the model and one to test the model

I don't want to use train_test_split of sklearn to split my data as it will my data randomly.I want some way out to query my data such that i can use some other sampling technique also i can't use stratified sampling as i don't have actual labels for these records

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'clean_id': [1,2,3,4],
   'all_terms': [['activation', 'brand', 'admin', 'sale', 'commission', 
                  'administration', 'assistant', 'manager'],
                 ['activation', 'brand', 'group', 'commission', 'mktg', 
                  'marketing', 'manager'],
                 ['activation', 'brand', 'info', 'specialist', 'service', 
                  'manager', 'customer'],
                 ['activation', 'brand', 'lead', 'greece', 'commission', 
                  'mktg', 'mgr', 'marketing']],
   'count_raw_id': [8,2,4,5]}
clean_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
len(clean_df)
#output : 2150
```

Answer (score 0):

K-Folds cross-validator should be helpful.

It provides train/test indices to split data in train/test sets. Split dataset into k consecutive folds (without shuffling by default).
Every fold is then used once as a validation while the k - 1 remaining folds form the training set.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

Or you can create your own logic the get samples. what query do you mean?

Comment: query as in some method to split my data into two sets

Comment: could you please elaborate how could i use k-fold cross method and is this method can be applied to the text column which contains tokens as i have mentioned in the code??

Comment: also, could you tell me how about uncertainty sampling to sample , as i have read something about it but i am not able to find a way to implement it !!

Comment: There is a good and simple example at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html.
Hope it is helpful.